# How do you tell which host is close to being blocked in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a two part question:

1. In cases were this error comes up, is there a way to see if a host is close to being blocked? And fire off an alert?

   ```
   PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1129] Host `hostname` is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with `mysqladmin flush-hosts`
   ```
2. What guidelines should one follow when increasing `max_connect_errors`-- ours is at 10? Is it recommended to run `mysqladmin flush-hosts` daily, via cron?

Running MySQL 5.5.13 (Enterprise) on Red Hat 6.

Comment: this is bad cuz you're opening your db to DOS attacks. is there anyway to whitelist certain hostnames so they never hit this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you should raise the [**max_connect_errors**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connect_errors) way beyond the default of 10.

The range is 1-18446744073709547520. I would set it to 1000 for now.

However, you have a bigger problem. [**mysqladmin**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html) requires you connect to mysqld before it does anything. If [**max_connect_errors**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connect_errors) is reached too quickly, you cannot make [**mysqladmin**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html) do anything at that point. Even a cron job will fail in this respect.

Since you are using MySQL 5.5, your best option is [**create a scheduled event within the MySQL Instance**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html) to go off every 5 minutes that will only do one thing: run [`FLUSH HOSTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html).

I just did this in MySQL 5.5.12 on my PC

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> CREATE EVENT ev ON SCHEDULE
    ->       EVERY 5 MINUTE
    -> STARTS (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
    -> DO FLUSH HOSTS;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql>
```

Great, no complaints from mysqld. Of course, I arbitrarily chose 5 minutes. You can choose whatever schedule you prefer.

Give it a Try !!!

**UPDATE 2011-08-25 11:22 EDT**

For everybody using release of MySQL prior to 5.1, I have a worthwhile suggestion:

Write a perl script that keeps an open connection, making it heartbeat itself by retrieving something (i.e., uptime, aborted_connects, etc) and every 10 minutes kicking out FLUSH HOSTS. Whatever user you connect as, make sure it has RELOAD privilege.

For example: run this command:

```
GRANT RELOAD on *.* to 'whateveruser'@'localhost' identified by 'whateverpassword';
```

Here is a perl script I call heartbeat.pl to do this using that user and password:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

my ($SLEEP_TIME_INTERVAL,$HEARTBEAT_CYCLE) = @ARGV;

$check_replication = 1;

$username = "whateveruser";
$password = "whateverpassword";

$MYSQL_HEARTBEAT_FILE = "/tmp/MySQLHeartBeat.txt";
$MYSQL_FLATLINE_FILE  = "/tmp/MySQLFlatLine.txt";

$MYSQL_PROCESSLIST_FILE = "/tmp/MySQL_Processlist.txt";

if ( $SLEEP_TIME_INTERVAL == 0 )
{
        open(fh_output,"> $MYSQL_FLATLINE_FILE") or die "Can't Find File $MYSQL_HEARTBEAT_FILE\n$!\n";
        printf fh_output "DONE !!!\n";
        close fh_output;
        exit 0;
}

$db = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:information_schema;host=127.0.0.1",$username,$password)
or die "Cannot connect to the DB information_schema\n",$DBI->errstr(),"\n";

$st_globalstatus = $db->prepare("SHOW GLOBAL STATUS") or die "Cannot Prepare SQL Statement\n",$DBI->errstr(),"\n";
$st_flush_hosts  = $db->prepare("FLUSH HOSTS")        or die "Cannot Prepare SQL Statement\n",$DBI->errstr(),"\n";

$heartbeat_count = 0;
$my_heart_is_beating = 1;
while ( $my_heart_is_beating )
{
        $st_globalstatus->execute() or die "Cannot Execute SQL Statement\n",$DBI->errstr(),"\n";
        {
                $StatusCount  = 0;
                while ( my $row = $st_globalstatus->fetchrow_hashref() )
                {
                        my $uptime = $row->{Value};
                }
                $st_globalstatus->finish();
                open(fh_output,"> $MYSQL_HEARTBEAT_FILE") or die "Can't Find File $MYSQL_HEARTBEAT_FILE\n$!\n";
                printf fh_output "%s : %s\n",$uptime;
                close fh_output;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < $SLEEP_TIME_INTERVAL; $i++)
        {
                if ( -f $MYSQL_FLATLINE_FILE )
                {
                        unlink $MYSQL_HEARTBEAT_FILE;
                        unlink $MYSQL_FLATLINE_FILE;
                        $my_heart_is_beating = 0;
                }
                sleep 1;
        }
        $heartbeat_count++;
        if ( $heartbeat_count == $HEARTBEAT_CYCLE )
        {
                $heartbeat_count = 0;
                $st_flush_hosts->execute();
        }
}

$db->disconnect();
```

In the OS, call the perl script to heartbeat every 6 seconds. When it heartbeats 100 times, that 600 seconds (10 minutes), make it run [`FLUSH HOSTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html). Call it like this:

```
nohup perl heartbeat.pl 6 100 &
```

Here are other schedules:

```
nohup perl heartbeat.pl  6  50 & (heartbeat every  6 sec,FLUSH HOSTS every 5 minutes)
nohup perl heartbeat.pl 10 360 & (heartbeat every 10 sec,FLUSH HOSTS every 1 hour)
nohup perl heartbeat.pl 60 180 & (heartbeat every 60 sec,FLUSH HOSTS every 3 hours)
```

To stop the program, run this:

```
perl heartbeat.pl
```

Comment: Thanks again for a comprehensive answer, I'll share it with the DBA to implement it.

Comment: good idea. does FLUSH HOSTS do anything but reset connection errors?