# Exclude IP from being blocked by MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql server running. Due to the uptime is not perfect, sometimes the HTTP server is blocked when mysql server is down intermittently.

```
Host 'host_name' is blocked because of many connection errors.
Unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

Currently, I have to set up a cron job to run "mysql-admin flush-hosts" to ensure my HTTP server can connect to database after the block.

My question is, how can I get certain IP (eg my HTTP Server) from being blocked by MySQL server ? Is it possible?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blocked-host.html

Answer (score 1):

I have a 4-year-old post on how to schedule `FLUSH HOSTS`:

- [How do you tell which host is close to being blocked in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5026/how-do-you-tell-which-host-is-close-to-being-blocked-in-mysql/5030#5030)

In that old post, I mentioned two techniques

- **TECHNIQUE #1** : Use MySQL Event (See the event code from my old post)
- **TECHNIQUE #2** : Run perl script (See the perl code from my old post)

  - Setup Parameters to Heartbeat
  - Connect to the mysqld
  - Hold DB Connection open indefinitely
  - Run `FLUSH HOSTS;` on the set schedule

In either case, `FLUSH HOSTS;` can be executed regularly.

Notwithstanding, you should be polling status variables

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name LIKE '%connect%';
```

to monitor connections attempts, dropped connections, and thing like these.